# Tone.js: Tone.start is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, tonejs

I'm struggling to simply get Tone.js to work at all. At first I realized I needed to activate the web audio context on a button click. However, now I'm running into this issue: `Tone.start is not a function`.

My code is the simplest, shortest possible I could get it:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tone.js</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <script type="module" src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button>Start</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

App.js:

```
import * as Tone from './node_modules/tone/build/Tone.js'

window.onload = function() {

    document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', startTone);
}

async function startTone() {
    await Tone.start();

}
```

This is based on the [official documentation](https://tonejs.github.io/), under "Starting Audio". Also for reference I'm running this in Chrome.

Comment: It might not be getting imported correctly. Check your network tab, correlate it with your file system, and also do `console.log(Tone)` to see what it is

Comment: No issues in the network tab... I console logged it at the top of window.onload and it shows: Module {Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): 'Module'}
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"

Comment: I assume you're not using any build here, just serving up the HTML and module directly? If so, try `import './node_modules/tone/build/Tone.js'`, or switch to a build and use the recommended `import * as Tone from 'tone'`.